# Is there another way to do this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.colorchooser import *
def get_color():
    color = askcolor()
    colorStr = str(color)
    colorHex = colorStr.rsplit("#", 1)[1]
    colorHex1 = colorHex.replace("'", " ")
    colorHex2 = colorHex1.replace(")", " ")
    print("#" + colorHex2)
root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
subMenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=False)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="Get Color", command=get_color)
root.geometry("300x250")
root.mainloop()
```

Is there another way to make the program print out the hex code?
An easier and faster way with less code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
def get_color():
    color = askcolor()
    print(color[1])
```

No need to convert the `color` tuple into a string and parse out the second element; you can just index it directly.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the nooby question. I'm a beginner.